# Is there a (possibly online) dictionary of electronics in Esperanto?

Tags: dictionaries

Electronics is a huge topic full of many technical terms, a lot of which have different names in different languages. I am referring to things like voltage, current (theoretical stuff), etc., components (diodes, resistors, transistors, etc.) and everything else that can possibly be included in this huge topic. Is there a dictionary (preferably online) in Esperanto for everything electronics-related?

Comment: http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/ --> fakoj --> elektro.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an online Eo-Eo dictionary of basic electrical terms (2MB, HTML):

- http://www.eventoj.hu/steb/vortaroj/elektra-terminaro.htm

And a sample of short articles:

- http://www.eventoj.hu/steb/ingxenierado/elektro/index-elektro.htm

The website [STEB](http://www.eventoj.hu/steb/) is a good place to look for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 3):

Komputeko.net is more about computer technology than electronics, but of the five specific words you mention, *resistor* is just plain missing, and though *current* doesn't appear by itself, there is a translation for *alternate current* which I assume is supposed to be *alternating current*.  I've found komputeko.net useful for words like *inbox*, *download*, et cetera, but *transistor*, *diode*, and *voltage* are all there.

Comment: I used it to translate sentences used from Drupal in Esperanto. I found it very useful for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Although not a dictionary, the website http://espleono.uw.hu/elektro.html may be of help for anyone trying to learn about electricity and electronics in Esperanto. The website includes textbooks, example (explained) circuits and even a reference for coloured components, all in Esperanto!

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of googling, I found this cool site that has an online picture list of terms of different types in different languages.  They have a section on Electronics.  Here's the link:
http://www.dicts.info/picture-dictionary.php?group=electronics&language=esperanto

Comment: Thanks! However, it does not seem to be a good reference. For example, for **resistor** it lists the word *rezisto*, while PIV has *rezistilo*, which should be the correct one.